# Equivalence classes and Disjoint Union

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. A relation from X to $Y$ is a subset $S$ of $X\times Y$.

Definition: Let $R$ be a relation on a set $X$. The equivalence relation $\sim$ generated by $R$ is defined to be by declaring $x\sim y$ $\iff$

there exists a sequence $x_1,...x_n$ $\in X$ such that

(1) $x_1=x, x_n=y$

(2) for each $i=1,...,n-1$, $x_iRx_{i+1}$ or $x_{i+1}Rx_i$ or $x_i=x_{i+1}$

Problem:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint topological spaces  and $A\subseteq Y$ be a closed subspace and $f:A\rightarrow X$ is a continuous map. Let the adjunction space be denoted by $(X\cup_f Y)/ \sim$. Where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on $X\cup_f Y$ generated by $a\sim f(a)$ for all $a\in A$. Show that the following are the equivalence classes of the above equivalence relation.

(1) $[x]=$ $\{$ $x$ $\}$ if $x\in X\backslash A$

(2) $[y]$ $=$ $\{$ y $\}$ if $y\in Y\backslash f(A)$

(3) $[a]=$ $f^{-1}(a) \cup$ $\{$ $f(a)$ $\}$  if $a\in A$.

I'm stuck on this problem. I would like help please. I would like a somewhat pedagogical explanation, please.

Comment: First if I am not mistaken you should exchange the role of $X$ and $Y$, either in the beginning of the problem or in the definition of the equivalence classes.
Then for your specific question I think only part $(3)$ is non-trivial and I am confused, I feel like it is wrong. Do you have more conditions on $f$?

Comment: I think $(3)$ should be $f^{-1}(a) \cup \{f(a)\}$ since any preimage of $f(a)$ should be in the same equivalence class.

Comment: @Nal you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Well by definition of your equivalence relation on $X\cup Y$:

(1) $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $x R y$ $\iff$ $x \in A$ and $y=f(x)$.
 
(2) $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $x_1 R x_2$ $\iff$ $x_1 = x_2$.
 
(3) $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ and $y_1 R y_2$$\iff$$y_1=y_2$.

You deduce from this that if $x_1, x_2 \in X$ are different and $x_1 \sim x_2$ then they must be in $A$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ (since the only way to get a chain between them, you must use $(1)$ two times: $x_1 R f(x_1)$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2) R x_2$). 
 
If $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ and $y_1 \sim y_2$ then using $R$ you can only have $y_1 =y_2$.
 
And finally, if $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$ the only way to get a chain between them is $x \in A$ and $x=f(x)$, you then use $(1)$ with $x R f(x)$.

Thus you have the desired equivalent classes: $[x]=\{x\}$ if $x \in X -A$, $[y]=\{y\}$ if $y \in Y -f(A)$ and $[a]=f^{-1}(a) \cup \{f(a)\}$ if $a \in A$.

Comment: Isn't my equivalence relation generated by $\{$ (a,f(a)) $:$ $a\in A$ $\}$ ? I am particularly confused on why the three if and only ifs hold.

Comment: $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ and $x\sim y$ $\iff$ there exists a finite sequence.... Why is this equivalent to $x\in A$ and $y=f(x)$?

Comment: I modified the answer considering your comment. I hope it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by "since the only way to get a chain between them..."? What is a chain?

Comment: A chain is a sequence $x_1, \dots x_n \in X \cup Y$ such that $x_i R x_{i+1}$ or $ x_{i+1}Rx_i $ or $x_i = x_{i+1}$ according to your definition of $\sim$. (With $R=\{ (a,f(a)),  \ a \in A\}$.)

Comment: What if $f(a) = f(b)$? Then you would have $aRf(a)$ and $bRf(b)$ and therefore $aRb$

Comment: Yes this is why $[a]= f^{-1}(a) \cup \{f(a)\}$ and not just $\{ a, f(a) \}$.

Comment: @Nal By $f^{-1}(a)$, you means $f^{-1}($ $\{$ a $\}$ ), right?

Comment: @topologicalmagician Yes exactly.

Comment: @Nal But $A\subseteq Y$, how can $f^{-1}(a)$ exist, if $f:A\rightarrow X$?

Comment: I think that it should be $A \subset X$ and $f: A \to Y$ in order to make sense. Then you'll have $f^{-1}(a) \subset X$ well defined.